# Extract IP address and port from each running Docker container

Tags: python, docker

For my service I am trying to create a Python script that extracts the IP address and port from all running Docker containers:

I used the following commands:

```
import os
import json


##1. Find all container ID
container_id = os.popen('docker ps -q').read()


##2. inspect all container
copy_2_json = os.popen('docker container inspect $(docker ps -q)').read()
print(json.loads(copy_2_json))
```

Could you please assist me on how should I proceed?
I have tried to save the output to text file but it didn't work also.

This is how the json file looks:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "bf960500ad8c68d8bbece532bdcb1fed32887ca988216fd6266d7f0b19530a47",
        "Created": "2018-09-13T13:27:13.8794826Z",
        "Path": "nginx",
        "Args": [
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 60064,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2018-09-13T13:27:14.7652514Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:c82521676580c4850bb8f0d72e47390a50d60c8ffe44d623ce57be521bca9869",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bf960500ad8c68d8bbece532bdcb1fed32887ca988216fd6266d7f0b19530a47/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bf960500ad8c68d8bbece532bdcb1fed32887ca988216fd6266d7f0b19530a47/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bf960500ad8c68d8bbece532bdcb1fed32887ca988216fd6266d7f0b19530a47/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/bf960500ad8c68d8bbece532bdcb1fed32887ca988216fd6266d7f0b19530a47/bf960500ad8c68d8bbece532bdcb1fed32887ca988216fd6266d7f0b19530a47-json.log",
        "Name": "/nginx",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/216d6a31d149a6d05dcfb7ac5e77aa389c42e93196fc3773d8d5cc73e37710e1-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5c59acc979633ac622494ba32369b6dbab5fe8c24b05c9a04acdccebde05f804/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b5a97ca4f1274cb1947342ff08769d709841469cf91e9dbe61a2c84305dcf951/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6de13aacf1daf2dcbdf805fe62705175a62504cf0143f334ba4493e86d8e5378/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/216d6a31d149a6d05dcfb7ac5e77aa389c42e93196fc3773d8d5cc73e37710e1/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/216d6a31d149a6d05dcfb7ac5e77aa389c42e93196fc3773d8d5cc73e37710e1/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/216d6a31d149a6d05dcfb7ac5e77aa389c42e93196fc3773d8d5cc73e37710e1/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "bf960500ad8c",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.15.2-1~stretch",
                "NJS_VERSION=1.15.2.0.2.2-1~stretch"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "nginx:latest",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "e62d9dc024c4276bd2f5ca00688c6552e2a8bb4d6a382112c84da34acb9951d0",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "80"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/e62d9dc024c4",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "d52386c5f54f950ba681ef993eba46338a52588fc2e71c60518eae82385771d3",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "d6c5276cdfe30c701a5f8133a6cbc2244b30cc0d1225990d73c278729f8e5ebf",
                    "EndpointID": "d52386c5f54f950ba681ef993eba46338a52588fc2e71c60518eae82385771d3",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you post the formats of json results?

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're running into?  It seems like you have the data you want in a Python dictionary already.  (Remember that the container-private IP address isn't very useful once you leave a development context and I'd try hard to not depend on it.)

Comment: my goal is to create a registry service, and for this, I need the IP and Port of the running container to call using curl command. I am struggling to export from json file the IP and save it to a variable.

Comment: Did you consider using tool like portainer? https://portainer.io/overview.html One of the screens called "Container list" gives the info you are looking for.

Comment: Curious, doesn't my answer do what you need or at least show you the path forward? What you are trying to do is relatively straightforward. Are you uncomfortable programming in Python? You can do all of this from bash using jq. Please let us know what you want and what language you want it in.

Comment: [Consul](https://consul.io/) and [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/)'s Service mechanism also both fill the same space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going. Note, port isn't in my docker NetworkSettings, so I didn't add it in because I couldn't test it. In general, for any field you can run docker inspect on a single container and see what information you want and easily extract it. From your json output, you probably just need to add {{.Port}} after {{.IPAddress}}.

In any case, the code example below should be able to get you everything you need. If not, let me know what else you require. Here you get the information as a Python dictionary (a variable) called 'output'.

```
# python 2.7

import os

# xargs command feeds each container to docker inspect
# You can add {{.Port}} after {{.IPAddress}}

cmd = "docker ps -q | xargs -r docker inspect --format \"'{{.Name }}': '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}',\""

output = os.popen(cmd).read()

output = eval("{" + output.replace("\n","").replace("/","") + "}")

# you now have a dictionary of the values; manipulate as necessary
# below i just print key(k) and value(v)
for k,v in zip(output.keys(), output.values()):
    print("Container: {} IP: {}".format(k,v))
```

Comment: In the cmd line there was an -r. I had to remove it. Without it runs very good.